# Joomla Version 1.5.23 login problem

Tags: joomla1.5

I am using Joomla Version 1.5.23 for my back end. I created a component called COM_DIRECTORY. I am using three kind of users.  like superadmin,sales person, advertisers person. if i login with sales person username and password , it will enter perfectly and if i click any link on my com_directory., it automatically logging out. Again if i use same use name and password and clicking the link it works fine.
Please resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Look if your links have www in the beginning of the link. If they do not, you must use .httacces file to rewrite them.

put this in your .httacces file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Dont forget to change yourdomain to your domain :)

Comment: Did you check the links? I had the same problem so please check the www in the beginning of the links.